# Generated Files and Functions in a JNI Project are all marked as syntax errors

Tags: java, c, eclipse, java-native-interface, jnienv

In a Project combining Java 8 and C, I built a JNI using javac -h [Directory] [.java File] and built the header, then included it in a C File where the native implementation was. I have everything needed for this: JDK, Cygwin, Eclipse that supports both Java and CDT, a Shared Library Project, but the generated functions have an ugly SYNTAX ERROR marked all over them and it's very unsightly, I so far cannot find a way to fix this, anyone have any ideas?

[Header for JNI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLfxU.png)

[C Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaGG6.png)

Comment: Are you including jni.h?

Comment: Yep, both Header and C File include jni.h

Comment: Well the C File also includes the header file, stdio and cl.h but i doubt it's that which is causing the problem